# Does getting two upvotes very often denote serial upvoting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

So, very often I have seemed to get exactly $2$ upvotes for a series of problems, but in no particular order in large quantity. What I mean by that is:

> Out of my 23 answers so far here, I have recieved 13 answers with exactly $2$ votes.

Now, I feel that often times, the answers specifically do not deserve the upvotes, etc, but I am not complaining. Is this phenomenon common, or am I getting serial upvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Getting exactly two upvotes on a large percentage of your answers does not itself denote serial voting. It could be a mere coincidence that your answers have been so received by the community-at-large. On the other hand, if the *same* account(s) are upvoting each of your answers, this would be more indicative of serial-type voting, or perhaps something even more sinister yet.

I'm sure our friendly neighborhood moderators will investigate and attempt to determine which of these possibilities current affect you.

Comment: AFAIK site moderators cannot see who voted on what. This is a privilege of SE employees (to be used in extreme situations only). Furthermore, I'd personally rather have our mods spend their time on dealing with what is explicitly in their scope (handling flags etc.) rather than chase after serial voting not severe (or dumb?) enough to trigger serial voting scripts.

Comment: @Lord_Farin From [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13153) it seems that moderators can see some stats about user-to-user voting, and a single user voting on 13 of the OP's answers would account for 130 of their 925 reputation points, which I think is a fairly high percentage and might show up in these stats. I would think that keeping an eye out for suspicious voting is also part of their explicit duties on this site. If the OP is concerned about being at the receiving end of serial voting, a simple (hopefully!) check by diamonds could also allay their fears.

Comment: Hm, I didn't know that. If it's that easy, then I suppose that it is reasonable to suggest a check. My response was more based on the only known route for me: contacting SE staff about this.